# What is a C1 and A1 chip?

Tags: identification

I'm fixing a Playstation 4 and Playstation 5 and I blew off a PS5 chip labeled C1. I managed to use a similar chip from a PS4 but it is labeled A1. What are these chips called and what do the labels mean?

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok edited question.

Comment: Replacing a "C1" with an "A1" could be like replacing a Subaru part with a Toyota part - i.e. it might fit, but no guarantee it will even work.  Need to decode those parts first.  Try searching for SMD Codes.

Comment: if `C1` blew up, then other parts are probably also damaged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a blind shot here, but that seems to be a [SOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Outline_Diode) package. So in this case it would be some kind of diode.
Not sure how to decode the label.

Comment: Yeah, the line on one side looks like a diode polarity marking. It's hard to guess what kind of diode it could be without knowing more about the surrounding circuit.